# How to send a custom tag associated with each SQL Server statement for trace filtering?

Tags: sql-server, profiling

I have a custom .NET app server that sends lots of SQL statements to a backend SQL Server. I have control on the code that runs in the app server and I can customize SQL Server in any way.

I need to send along with each statement a custom tag that is visible as a SQL trace column so that I can filter the traces by these custom tags.

I can't use SQL connection's ApplicationName because this is connection specific and connections are pooled in the app server and assigned randomly to statements. If I change ApplicationName before each statement the pooling breaks down and the connection needs to be redone and that's too much of a penalty.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Note: I had the idea of altering each statement that goes through an SqlCommand and prefix the T-SQL with a comment (/*CustomTags tag1 tag12*/) or a dummy statement (SELECT 'tag1', 'tag5') but I feel there must be a better way. I need this to do business oriented profiling. The tags come from the client, pass through the app server and I want to glue them to SQL statements in order to have some immediate feedback on how much load a certain business action/module generates on the db server)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to customize the SQL that is being sent, you can put your tag in as part of a table alias.  This has the added benefit of even being able to include Showplan XML Statistics Profile events to get actual query plans and filter out everything except your target queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables as YourFilterHere
INNER JOIN sys.columns 
  ON YourFilterHere.object_id = columns.object_id
```

You can then filter TextData like %YourFilterHere%

Comment: It can't work for me. It would mean having to manually alter thousands of existing SQL statements (which is simply not doable manually) and it would impact performance because the same logical SQL statement would be multiplied by the number of tags and seen as different by the server, leading to at least some caching not working, overhead for additional compilation, etc.